# Looping Command Ends up Crashing Every Time Run in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to make a constant checking macro that adds the level when the progress hits 100% (in Excel macro or VBA).

[image]

What I expected:

`[Current Progress = {Hits 100%}] -> [Current Level = {Current number + 1}]`

```
Sub Check_Progress()
    Do While Range("e9") = True
        Do While Range("c8") >= 1
            Range("c10") = Range("c10") + 1
        Loop
        Do While Range("c8") < 0
            Range("C10").Value = Range("c10") - 1
        Loop
    Loop
End Sub
```

But this macro always ends in a crash no matter in what condition.

Comment: We can't do anything here before you explain how this is supposed to work. Start with the formulas in `C8` and `E9`.

Comment: When you check cell C8 as condition in a loop but don't modify C8 in that loop, you will be trapped in an endless loop.

Comment: basically, i used VLookUp function on `C9` (Current XP needed to level up value) that refers to `C10` (Current level value), so when `C10` turns into "2" the `C9` will change based on the list (changed by changing the power value [`C5`]), and then `C8` (progress precentage value) will turns back into 0% by changing the value of C9 and `subtracting the total xp value with the deference points of every level` (`D8`) (C8 = current xp point (`D8`) / C9)

and for the case of `E9`, it's only a switch to turn the loop on and off (well, that's what i tought)